# Grabbing image with requests and encoding with base64, but headers are incorrect

Tags: python, image, python-requests

I'm writing code to download an image from a URL, then encode that image in `base64`. The relevant section of the code is:

```
dlimage = requests.request("GET", imageURL)
encodedImage = ("data:" + dlimage.headers['Content-Type'] + ";" + "base64," + base64.encodestring(dlimage.content))
```

The resulting output is:

```
data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD48dGl0bGU+NDAzIEZvcmJpZGRlbjwvdGl0bGU+PC9oZWFkPg0KPGJvZHkgYmdjb2xvcj0id2hpdGUiPg0KPGNlbnRlcj48aDE+NDAzIEZvcmJpZGRlbjwvaDE+PC9jZW50ZXI+DQo8aHI+PGNlbnRlcj5uZ2lueDwvY2VudGVyPg0KPC9ib2R5Pg0KPC9odG1sPg0K
```

The image in question is a `JPEG`. So why are the headers saying `text/html`? I converted the image using another tool, and the string is totally different.

Comment: what is the value of this: dlimage.headers['Content-Type']? It looks like the value of that header is "text/html". Instead of accessing that array to get the header, why dont you just hard code what you need because it will always be an image. so instead of dlimage.headers['Content-Type'] you should have "image/jpeg"

Comment: Can't hardcode image/jpeg because occasionally the downloaded images will be PNGs or GIFs.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with that header. The server is not setting it properly. Do you have access to the server side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is *not* a JPEG file.

A [JPEG file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure) starts with the bytes 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF. In base64 encoding that becomes `/9j/` (example in IPython with Python 3.6):

```
In [1]: start = b'\xff\xd8\xff'

In [2]: base64.b64encode(start).decode('ascii')
Out[2]: '/9j/'
```

Since your base64 encoded string starts different, it is not a JPEG file.

Decoding the content:

```
In [3]: base64.b64decode('PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD48dGl0bGU+NDAzIEZvcmJpZGRlbjwvdGl0bGU+PC9oZWFkPg0KPGJvZHkgYm
    ...: djb2xvcj0id2hpdGUiPg0KPGNlbnRlcj48aDE+NDAzIEZvcmJpZGRlbjwvaDE+PC9jZW50ZXI+DQo8aHI+PGNlbnRlcj5uZ2
    ...: lueDwvY2VudGVyPg0KPC9ib2R5Pg0KPC9odG1sPg0K')
Out[3]: b'<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

You don't have access to the image...